# How to make actionscript run once?

Tags: actionscript

When I add actionscript to a Flash movie, it runs every time the movie enters a new loop. How do I make it run only once, when the movie has finished loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set a flag telling you if the script has already executed. Like this;

```
var done:Boolean;
if (!done) {

    // any code here will run only once.

    done=true;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have actually tried the same exact thing, except it didn't work that time :/

Comment: np. the trick is to only declare the variable. var done:Boolean = false; wont work.

Comment: actually I think I did declare it as done:Boolean = false!